# Matching a wrapped pattern

Tags: php, regex

What regex pattern can be used for finding word with a following dot that are in a parentheses pair.

> as. df.kj hlasfa (**asd.**  las **kdfh.**) dfs adk jfh. a (sd.kf) jhd (dsk
>   ***fh.***) dskfdf asdf dfs lkjh asdfdsfjkhlkjh (**asdf.**)as fadf asf

Desired results are bolded.

Comment: Should (sd.kf) also be bolded ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV No. It should not

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many options is:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+[.](?=[ )])(?=[^(]*[)])
```

Comment: @Reza - No lookbehinds. First positive lookahead `(?=[ )])` ensure there is a space or closing round bracket right behind the period. Second positive lookahead `(?=[^(]*[)])` ensure there is closing round bracket somewhere behind with no opening round bracket between the period and such closing round bracket.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that asserts that there is no opening parenthesis before the next closing one:

```
preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]+\.(?![a-zA-Z])(?=[^()]*\))/', $input, $matches);
```

You will find the four matches in `$matches`.

The first negative lookahead eliminates the case mentioned by HamZa in the comment. The second (positive) lookahead tries to find a closing parenthesis before the next opening one.

There is a caveat here. This will start to crumble once you have nested parentheses. `some(text. (here))` would not match `text.`. Nested patterns (which can occur from using parentheses) are generally beyond the scope of regular expressions, although some engines can partly handle them. If this is the case for you, you are better of going through the string manually and counting parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, Is not recursion applicable here too?

Comment: @Reza In PHP recursion only really makes sense to check for the correct structure of an input string. For matching and replacing it is not really applicable, because you can only get one result per capturing group. So nested occurrences of the required pattern can not be retrieved in one go.

Comment: Thanks again. I confused! Can you please explain second lookahead  a little more.

Comment: @Reza, input: `(a(b(c)d)e)`, pattern `(\(\w*(?R)?\w*\))`. this will easily match the whole string. but also note that I added a capturing group `(...)` around the whole pattern. what you would want (and need to use recursion for your original question) are three captured results: `(a(b(c)d)e)`, `(b(c)d)`, `(c)`. But PCRE wil give you only one of those (since it is a reuse of the same capturing group). This could only be accomplished using recursion in  .NET, I think (where you can access multiple captures of a single group).

Comment: @Reza I just realized that myself and edited the solution half a minute ago ^^